# MongoDB C# driver ObjectId serialization issue in projection

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I am having trouble in finding the issue behind the serialization exception here. I have two model class as parent and child. and I am writing a mongodDB query to get the list of childs which matches the ids values from given string array of ids.

```
public class Parent
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string ChildId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I am wrting the following aggregate query using the MongoDB driver to filter the childs which Id matches with given string array of id

```
string parentId = "638a4259e431d53971444ba4";
string[] childIds = new string[] { "638d1b92c50872c01df4a8fb", "6398dc29ca4933fb1e4f0644" };

var findParentFilter = Builders<Parent>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ParentId, parentId);
            var projection = Builders<Parent>.Projection
                .Include(q => q.ParentId)
                .Include(q => Builders<Child>.Filter.In(x => x.ChildId, childIds));

var returnVal = quizCollection.Aggregate().Match(findParentFilter).Project<Parent>(projection);

var result = returnVal .FirstOrDefault();
```

After the returnVal I am getting the exception as follows.

```
{"Unable to determine the serialization information for q => Builders`1.Filter.In(x => x.ChildId, value(NetCoreSampleAPI.Core.DBRepository.ParentRepository+<>c__DisplayClass7_0).childIds)."}
```

I am expecting it to run correctly, looks like I am missing some serialization but the normal find query in another function is working fine. Looks like something with the BsonId and string value comparision. Can someone help? I basically want to write following query using Builder.

Comment: Hello, As error states, In method doesn't recognize string array. Could you give it a try with, List<string> ?  And also you can try it with AnyIn.

Comment: The error says something about NetCoreSampleAPI.Core.DBRepository.ParentRepository. Is it your class? Do you really take child IDs from a string array or do you use some repository query?

Comment: yes, it is my class. I am taking the childId's from string array, the array is passed as input parameter of the function which contains this code.

Comment: I have tried with List<string> in fact I have converted the strings to ObjectIds as well but no luck.